# How to use Assisted Inject and Inject with dagger hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have ViewModel where I need in runtime inject some parameters but also in this ViewModel i need repository. Not sure is it possible with dagger hilt to combine Assisted Inject and Inject. If I try now to use communityFeedRepository it gives me error:

> com.test.context.community.repository.CommunityFeedRepository is
> injected at com.test.context.community.CommunityFeedViewModel(…,
> communityFeedRepository)
> com.test.context.community.CommunityFeedViewModel.Factory is requested
> at
> com.test.context.di.ViewModelFactoryProvider.communityFeedViewModelFactory()

Here is my code:

```
class CommunityFeedViewModel
@AssistedInject
constructor(
    @Assisted("preloadedTiles") private val preloadedTiles: List<Tile>,
    @Assisted("path") private val path: String,
    @Assisted("token") private val token: String?,
    // private var communityFeedRepository: CommunityFeedRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    
    var tiles: List<Tile> = preloadedTiles
    private val vmPath = path
    var vmToken: String? = token

    private val tileState = MutableStateFlow(tiles)
    val til = tileState.asStateFlow()

    private suspend fun loadTiles() {
        /*communityFeedRepository.getCommunityFeedTiles(vmPath, vmToken).onSuccess {
            tileState.value = it.tiles
            vmToken = it.token
        }*/
    }

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (tiles.isEmpty()) {
                loadTiles()
            }
        }
    }

    @AssistedFactory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
            @Assisted("preloadedTiles") preloadedTiles: List<Tile>,
            @Assisted("path") path: String,
            @Assisted("token") token: String?
        ): CommunityFeedViewModel
    }
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    companion object {
        fun provideFactory(
            assistedFactory: Factory,
            preloadedTiles: List<Tile>,
            path: String,
            token: String?
        ): ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return assistedFactory.create(preloadedTiles, path, token) as T
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun communityFeedViewModel(
    preloadedTiles: List<Tile>,
    path: String,
    token: String?
): CommunityFeedViewModel {
    val factory = EntryPointAccessors.fromActivity(
        LocalContext.current as Activity,
        ViewModelFactoryProvider::class.java
    ).communityFeedViewModelFactory()

    return viewModel(
        factory = CommunityFeedViewModel.provideFactory(
            factory,
            preloadedTiles = preloadedTiles,
            path = path,
            token = token
        ), key = path
    )
}
```

Comment: could you write complete error message

Answer (score 2):

Ah I think I found error and it works fine. If somebody run into similar issues might be helpful. I have AssistedModule

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
interface ViewModelFactoryProvider {
    fun communityFeedViewModelFactory(): CommunityFeedViewModel.Factory
}
```

and it is installed in ActivityComponent. I had issues where my CommunityModule had install in ViewModelComponent. I make it like this and now all works fine.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object CommunityFeedModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideCommunityFeedApi(retrofit: Retrofit): CommunityFeedApi = retrofit.create(CommunityFeedApi::class.java)

    @Provides
    fun provideCommunityFeedRepository(communityFeedApi: CommunityFeedApi): CommunityFeedRepository =
        CommunityFeedRepositoryImpl(communityFeedApi)
}
```

Comment: The "somebody run into similar issues" is me :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Dagger 2.49](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.49), assisted injection is properly supported in Hilt: https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model#assisted-injection

This is how your ViewModel should look like:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel(assistedFactory = MyViewModel.Factory::class)
class MyViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
  @Assisted val runtimeArg: String,
  private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
  private val someDependency: SomeDependency,
) : ViewModel() {
  @AssistedFactory interface Factory {
    fun create(runtimeArg: String): MyViewModel
  }
  ...
}
```

And this is how you can create it:

```kotlin
private val myViewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>(
  extrasProducer = {
    defaultViewModelCreationExtras.withCreationCallback<MyViewModel.Factory> { factory -> 
      factory.create(runtimeArg = "abc")  
    }
  }
)

// or in Compose:
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel, MyViewModel.Factory>(
  creationCallback = { factory -> factory.create(runtimeArg = "abc") }
)
```

I have `SavedStateHandle` as a dependency there just as a reminder it can be added as a regular dependency since it's a binding from `ViewModelComponent`.